# Craft CMS Headless - Preview mode

Tags: live-preview, headless

I'm new on craft and I'm using headless mode with a nextJs frontend application.

I've tried to configure the preview mode to load the frontend, but I didn't find how to do that. The frontend application it's already looking for a token in the URL to send it back, but I don't know how to configure it on the craft side.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: did you find a solution?